# Basic jQueryUI function for image uploader

Tags: jquery-ui, image-upload

I've been trying to wrap my head around a very basic Javascript/jQuery task.

I've made a basic image uploader with the following HTML:

```
div class="button one"></div>
    <div class="button two"></div>

    <div class="size ui-widget-content">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <input type='file' name='userFile'>
    </div>

    <div class="button three"></div>
```

This is the code I've got so far, from the jQueryUI plugin:

```
$( ".size" ).resizable( { 
    grid: [60, 24],
    ghost: true,
    aspectRatio: //ratio function here ,
    stop: function( event , ui) {
        var height = $(".size").css( "height" );
        var width = $(".size").css( "width" );
        $( ".size img" ).css( { width : width, height: height })

   }
});

$( ".size > input" ).change(function() {
    var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
    var height = $(".size").css( "height" );
    var width = $(".size").css( "width" );

    $( ".size img" ).css( { width : width, height: height } );  
    $( ".size img" ).attr("src" , filename);
    $( ".size img" ).attr("alt", filename );

    $( ".three" ).show();

    var fr = new FileReader;
    fr.onload = function() { // file is loaded
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function() {
            var maxWidth = 960;
            var maxHeight = maxWidth * (img.height/img.width);
            $( ".size, .size img" ).css( { width : img.width, height: img.height, "max-height": maxHeight , "max-width": maxWidth});
        };
    img.src = fr.result; // is the data URL because called with readAsDataURL
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]); // I'm using a <input type="file"> for demonstrating
});
```

What I want to do is the following:
I'm trying to upload an image from my harddrive onto the page.

So far, so good.

I've used the jQueryUI Resizable function so that I can resize the image. This works perfectly.

The problem however, is that I dont know how to get the right image ratio into the Resizable function. I need this function so that my image will keep its original aspect ratio when I start resizing it.

Basically, I need to get a value from the $( ".size > input" ).change function into the aspectRatio property of the $( ".size" ).resizable function

Any ideas on how to do this?

----------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------

I've tried @Frédéric Hamidi's solution but it doesnt work either.
I've editted the code to:

```
$(".size").resizable("option", "start", function( event , ui){
        $(".size").resizable("option", "aspectRatio", 3 / 4);
});
```

But this doesnt work either. The Firebug console says:

*Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on resizable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'*

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [aspectRatio](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-aspectRatio) property in your `change` handler, after the widget has been initialized, through the setter form of the widget's [option()](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#method-option) method.

```
$(".size > input").change(function() {

    // Your current code...

    $(this).parent().resizable("option", "aspectRatio", yourComputedAspectRatio);
});
```

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work. The aspectRatio didnt get set, not even if I hardcoded the aspectRatio to 3 / 4

Comment: I know this is really old, but it's probably worth noting that this _will_ be the correct answer once this JQueryUI bug is fixed https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4186 it's been around for 8 years apparently, but it looks like it may actually get fixed in the next version 1.12.2